# How create dynamically object in loop but with "if else" statement

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to make na object like this:

```
let userNames = {
    user0: {
        company: "Company 431"
        name: ["user0", "user32"],
        mail: ["user0@mail431.com", "user32@mail431.com"],
    },
    user1: {
        company: "Company 34"
        name: ["user12", "user26"],
        mail: ["user12@mail34.com", "user26@mail34.com"],
    },
    user2: {
        company: "Company 420"
        name: ["user21", "user37"],
        mail: ["user21@mail420.com", "user37@mail420.com"],
    }
};
```

I have 2 objects, first is with company (and something else but is not important) and second for name and mail.
Important is that mails have same numbers as company.

This is example from my code;

```
let j = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length;){                  //arr.length is 2500 arr1 is 1000
 
    if(arr[i].uri == arr1[j].uris){               //if true i want push values to mail and name (on user0 on start)
        i++
    }else{                                        //if false i make only new user and then again push name and mail 
        j++;
    }
}
```

I don't have idea how initializate and then push values to this (i know about .push()), without destroying initializated object.

Comment: Create a complete snippet include all object with tool `<>`

Comment: what is `arr` (company or name/mail) and what is `arr1`? what is uri (the part that isn't important)?

Comment: Uri and uris are things comparisons (it's look otherwise in my code because it's only for example). 
from arr1 i want get company, and from arr2 i want get name and mail.